# How can I convert a Base64 string to a float array or int array?

Tags: c#, linq, base64

I have some code that converts a `float[]` to a `Base64` string:

```
float[] f_elements = <from elsewhere in my code>;
byte[] f_vfeat = f_elements.SelectMany(value => BitConverter.GetBytes(value)).ToArray();
string f_sig = Convert.ToBase64String(f_vfeat);
```

I also have - *basically* - the same code that converts an `int[]` to a `Base64` string:

```
int[] i_elements = <from elsewhere in my code>;
byte[] i_feat = i_elements.SelectMany(value => BitConverter.GetBytes(value)).ToArray();
string i_sig = Convert.ToBase64String(i_feat);
```

Both of these produce `Base64` strings as expected. However, now I need to decode back to an array, and I'm running into trouble.

How can I go from my `Base64` string(s), and get the original data array(s). Before I decode the `Base64` string, I will know if it is suppose to be an `int[]` or `float[]`, so I think that will help.

Does anyone know how to do go from `Base64` string to `float[]` or `int[]`?

Comment: I think that you may be wanting to look at [MSDN File.WriteAllBytes Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) also for testing purposes can you post a sample of what the string looks like..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `BitConverter.ToInt32` or `BitConverter.ToSingle` to convert part of an array:

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String();
int[] ints = new int[bytes.Length / 4];
for (int i = 0; i < ints.Length; i++)
{
    ints[i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, i * 4);
}
```

(And the equivalent for `ToSingle`, of course.)

In my view, it's a shame that `GetBytes` doesn't have an overload to write the bytes directly into an existing array, instead of creating a new array on each call...

Comment: Is the `bytes.Length / 4` and `i * 4` using **4** because an `Int32` and a `Single` are 4 bytes? If one of the arrays was suppose to be a `double[]`, would I change that **4** to **8**?

Comment: @Brett: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something wrong with [`Convert.FromBase64String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

```
byte[] i_feat = Convert.FromBase64String(i_sig)
```

Comment: I need to go from byte[] to `float[]` or `int[]` after that. @JonSkeet's answer below looks like it does this, looking at it now.

Comment: Oh, I see that he answered all that while I was typing. Tough competition there!